# React input type change fires blur event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, ecmascript-6

I have an input field in react (as bootstrap FormControl), which changes its type from text to number if it is on focus.

The idea is that the user can only enter numbers, but if it is not in focus, it changes back to the text and shows the unit as well. This works fine in chrome. However, in firefox when I change the type of the input field or destroy it (render conditionally) it fires a blur event.

So my question: Is there any way to distinguish between the blur event fired by firefox (on destroying or type change) and the blur fire by the user focusing on something else?

The behaviour can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexus37/ypq9c8La/24/).

```
onBlur() => this.setState({ focused: false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding `e.preventDefault()` or `e.stopPropagation()` in the onBlur function. However, you can check the relatedTarget on the onBlur event. If the relatedTarget isn't the input field, `focus` will be `focus:false`. Maybe it is not the best approach but it works.

```
  onBlur(e) {
    console.log('blur is called');
    if(!e.relatedTarget || e.relatedTarget.className !== "form-control" ) {
     this.setState({ focused: false });
    } 
  }
```

Comment: This makes the input in firefox editable. However, when I leave the input it does not change its type back to text.

Comment: relatedTarget was null for me, however, this comment fixed it https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2011#issuecomment-76071919. Thanks